# como criar uma função que verifica se duas listas são iguais sem usar o operador (==)?

Tags: funções, haskell

```
iguais:: [Int]->[Int]->Bool
iguais [] [] = True
iguais [] _ = False
iguais _ [] = False
iguais (x:xs) (z:zs)
```

esse é o código, só fiz ate ai. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `iguais a b = not (a /= b)`  ok, ok, acho que não era isto que querias...

Comment: não, na verdade eu quero uma chamada recursiva.

Comment: `x == z && iguais xs zs` na tua ultima linha? (ou `not( x /= z) && iguais xs zs` )

Comment: Não vale nem `==` pra fazer a comparação de `x == z` ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei isso:

```hs
iguais :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
iguais [] [] = True
iguais [] (_:_) = False
iguais (_:_) [] = False
iguais (x:xs) (x:ys) = iguais xs ys
iguais _ _ = False -- Se chegar aqui eh porque nao deu match na idefinicao de cima
```

Mas obtive o seguinte erro `Conflicting definitions for ‘x’`.
Descobri que **não é possível**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179394/858412